# Elasticsearch : case_sensitive parameter to the wildcard operator return errors

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch, wildcard, case-insensitive

On **Elastic search**, it is possible to add a case_sensitive parameter to the wildcard operator.
I tried the following code without success:

```
wildcard: {
                  'attribute_values.text_value.keyword': {
                    value: '*' + textValue + '*',
                    case_insensitive: true
                  }
                },
```

The error that is returned to me is :

ResponseError: parsing_exception

```
  at onBody (../node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:337:23)
  at IncomingMessage.onEnd (../node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:264:11)
```

I've searched on Google and Stackoverflow but I didn't find anything that works.

Does anyone have any idea where this error may have come from?
I have version 7.12 of Elasticsearch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized that my local version of elastic search was in 7.5.2 and not in 7.12.

Problem solved